# Can we work with external APIs in Azure Databricks?

Tags: api, azure-databricks

Being newbie to Databricks just exploring ways to access third party APIs in Databricks.

```
   Example : 
      One of the sceanario is checking whether json file which is being 
      processed via Databricks whether its in correct Json format or not?
      We have one API which validate this format, question is can we consume
      this API in Databricks notebook ?
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little unclear on the exact nature of what you're trying to do but databricks supports external libraries, and through those, REST API calls, e.g. Python's `request` library. If you click `clusters` in the sidebar, followed by the cluster you're using, you should see a tab labeled `libraries`. From there you can click `install new` to install whatever you want. [This page](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/libraries.html) should provide you with further information.